# #skrollr-body makes all content invisible on mobile

Tags: jquery, ios, wordpress, mobile

I'm using Skrollr.js for parallax https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr. I specifically tested this on mobile at the start of development to make sure it worked on Mobile. Initially it worked perfectly on my iphone 4S version 6.1.3. It's a wordpress site...and I updated Wordpress recently to version 3.5.2. , so I hope that didn't break it. But now when I put #skrollr-body as a wrap for the site, it makes everything invisible on mobile. I haven't been able to find anyone with this particular problem online, so I guess I'm trying to figure out any ideas why this would be happening suddenly. I even tried messing with z-index, position, visibility, display, etc. But nothing helped.

Any ideas? Unfortunately I can't really provide a link to the site because I'm deving for a client...but if you need any excerpts of code let me know what might help assist me.

Please Help!!! :)

Comment: Which skrollr version?

Comment: I can't really help much without code. Try the following: Open the page in Chrome, open the inspector and check "Emulate touch events" and set the user-agent to iOS. After a page reload you can debug what's hiding your page.

Comment: Hmm, while investigating I figured out it has something to do with conflicting with superfish.js I am using a Genesis theme for wordpress which uses superfish. If I remove the superfish import then everything works fine. So I guess I have to figure out what the conflict is.

Answer (score 0):

Ha, seems that I just had to update Superfish.js to v1.7.4. I had v1.4.8. Now Superfish dropdowns don't seem to work on mobile, but perhaps that was always the case. Thanks for the help though Prinzhorn. :)